# jvm condition and locksupport which is faster?

Tags: jvm, synchronized

An experimental example of synchronous call is made. Each thread task waits for a task callback with its own value of + 1. The performance difference between condition and locksupport is compared. The result is unexpected. The two times are the same, but the difference on the flame diagram is very big. Does it mean that the JVM has not optimized locksupport

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iMdPu.png)
public class LockerTest {

```
static int max = 100000;
static boolean usePark = true;

static Map<Long, Long> msg = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
static ExecutorService producer = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
static ExecutorService consumer = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(16);
static AtomicLong record = new AtomicLong(0);
static CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(max);

static ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();
static Condition cond = lock.newCondition();

static Map<Long, Thread> parkMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

static AtomicLong cN = new AtomicLong(0);

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for (int num = 0; num < max; num++) {
        consumer.execute(() -> {
            long id = record.incrementAndGet();
            msg.put(id, -1L);
            call(id);

            if (usePark) {
                Thread thread = Thread.currentThread();
                parkMap.put(id, thread);
                while (msg.get(id) == -1) {
                    cN.incrementAndGet();
                    LockSupport.park(thread);
                }
            } else {
                lock.lock();
                try {
                    while (msg.get(id) == -1) {
                        cN.incrementAndGet();
                        cond.await();
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    lock.unlock();
                }
            }
            latch.countDown();
        });
    }

    latch.await();
    consumer.shutdown();
    producer.shutdown();

    System.out.printf("park %s suc %s cost %s cn %s"
            , usePark
            , msg.entrySet().stream().noneMatch(entry -> entry.getKey() + 1 != entry.getValue())
            , System.currentTimeMillis() - start
            , cN.get()
    );
}

private static void call(long id) {
    producer.execute(() -> {
        try {
            Thread.sleep((id * 13) % 100);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (usePark) {
            msg.put(id, id + 1);
            LockSupport.unpark(parkMap.remove(id));
        } else {
            lock.lock();
            try {
                msg.put(id, id + 1);
                cond.signalAll();
            } finally {
                lock.unlock();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: You are using a `ReentrantLock` which can be acquired by only one thread at a time. Combined with a single `Condition` for all of them, despite waiting for different things. So you unpark all threads, all of them having to compete for the lock, to find that all but one were unparked pointlessly and have to park again. Then, you compare the result with the alternative of directly unparking the correct thread without a lock…

Comment: Yes, I also think that using ReentrantLock will wake up unnecessary threads to compete for lock resources, so I use the unpark method to specify waiting threads to wake up and reduce thread state switching. But in actual testing, there is no reduction in time, which makes me feel whether I have cognitive errors

Comment: If you use `ReentrantLock` and have threads waiting for different conditions, you should create multiple `Condition`s. Then, the signaling thread can precisely tell which conditions has been fulfilled, instead of waking up all threads. Of course, if the overhead overlaps with threads doing just `Thread.sleep`, you may not experience a difference in total execution time, you just change the CPU load during the test.